# Sheets disappearing from sheet tab after script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I've written this simple function to copy a range from one sheet to another.
But suddenly after the script is run (with the expected result) the sheet disappear from the sheet tab and I can only select it by clicking on the "all sheet" button

[image: screenshot]

This is the function:

```
function newclient() {
 var spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
 var data = sheet.getRange('A3:Q7');


 var destinationsheet = spread.getSheetByName('2017'); 
 var destinationrange = destinationsheet.getRange(destinationsheet.getLastRow()+1, 1);
 data.copyTo(destinationrange);
 Browser.msgBox("Hai aggiunto un nuovo Cliente"); 
}
```

Comment: How do you call the script? Are there other scripts on your script project?

Comment: There's nothing in that code that would effect the visibility of a sheet.